# Backend for iOS app

Tags: ios6, titanium, titanium-mobile, kal

My question is how do i get information from a server to my iphone app. let's assume I have completed my current project I'm working on that only needs data to be uploaded to my application.

I understand there is a database or server I must create but how do I go about creating or modifying one for my needs.

I mainly want to store login information from one user and allow users to search for people who have entered login information (name) to add to a friends lists within the current app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think in your case you can use Django-tastypie for backend will be good choice.since using django you can develop it in quick time and the tastypie has api services which can used easily for retrieval and sending data

you can go through this

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: With my groups plan, we are going through with me developing the interface and functionality of the iphone app, another person will work on getting a server running for me to send small information to. We are going to use sockets to do this. The backend is basically written in c++ but I am very lost on what is going on with everyone else's part other than mine, getting a user's information stored inside the database as well as being able to edit such information.

Comment: It will be difficult at starting.. You can do it with little bit paper work. put on paper ,draw flowcharts about flow how to store and how to do. You will get it

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at services like Stackmob or Parse.  These types of service could make it really easy for you to get the server side part of your application up and running.  These services would act as your database and also provide an easy api for you to access the server side pieces.